# Snakemake concatenate multiple files

Tags: python, bash, snakemake

i want to concatenate individual chromosome files (labelled chromosome 1, X and M) for each sample (sample 1-4). each sample has 3 chromosome file.

here's Final files that i want to create

```
result/sample1_merged_chr1XM.txt
result/sample2_merged_chr1XM.txt
result/sample3_merged_chr1XM.txt
result/sample4_merged_chr1XM.txt
```

using the command

```
cat dirToFiles/sample1_chr_1_data.txt dirToFiles/sample1_chr_X_data.txt dirToFiles/sample1_chr_M_data.txt > result/sample1_merged.txt
cat dirToFiles/sample1_chr_2_data.txt dirToFiles/sample2_chr_X_data.txt dirToFiles/sample2_chr_M_data.txt > result/sample2_merged.txt
cat dirToFiles/sample1_chr_3_data.txt dirToFiles/sample3_chr_X_data.txt dirToFiles/sample3_chr_M_data.txt > result/sample3_merged.txt
cat dirToFiles/sample1_chr_4_data.txt dirToFiles/sample4_chr_X_data.txt dirToFiles/sample4_chr_M_data.txt > result/sample4_merged.txt
```

here i am attaching a reproducible code to create files and merge the files afterwards

```
#######################################
#Step 1: create multiple files to merge
######################################

import subprocess
subprocess.run((['mkdir','-p', 'dirToFiles']))

SAMPLES = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4"]
CHROMS=["1", "X", "M"]

for sample in SAMPLES:
    for chrom in CHROMS:
        subprocess.run((['touch', f'dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}_data.txt']))
        # subprocess.run((['echo', '"',str(sample),'"', '>>', f'dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}_result.txt'])) #this doesn't work,

for sample in SAMPLES:
    for chrom in CHROMS:
        f = open(f'dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}_data.txt', "w")
        f.write(f'dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}_data.txt')
        f.close()

#expand("dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}_data.txt",sample=SAMPLES, chrom=CHROMS),

#################################
#Step 2: snakemake rules
#################################
SAMPLES = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4"]
CHROMS = ["1", "X", "M"]

rule all:
    input: expand("result/{sample}_merged_chr1XM.txt",sample=SAMPLES)


rule combineFiles:
    input:
        expand("dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}_data.txt", chrom=CHROMS, partial=True)
    output:
        "result/{sample}_merged_chr1XM.txt"
    log: 
        "logs/{sample}_merged_chr1XM.txt"
    shell:
       """
 cat {input} > {output} &> {log}
       """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rule `combineFiles`, you are using `expand` and providing both `sample` and `chrom` for expansion. This means that the input will contain the full list that contains the cartesian product of both wildcard values.

What you are looking for instead is providing just one expansion, of `chrom` wildcard. For this use `allow_missing=True` kwarg:

```py
rule combineFiles:
    input:
        expand("dirToFiles/{sample}_chr_{chrom}/result.csv", chrom=CHROMS, allow_missing=True)
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions but that didn't work! error `No values given for wildcard 'sample'.` I'm attaching a reproducible code/example to original post

Comment: Oops, sorry, I mis-remembered the kwarg. I updated the answer.

Comment: you are a genius! `allow_missing=True` worked! Also how can i capture `{input}` as  string in the shell to use as argument? ie  `shell: "Rscript {params.gatherFilesScript} --inputFiles {input} --outputFiles {output} &> {log}"` where the concatenating is done by the Rscript

Comment: Haha, thanks! Not sure if you mean quoting (using double quotations)? If so, then use `{input:q}`.

Comment: actually quoted list of strings as input. so the shell should be  interpreted as this `Rscript gatherFilesScript --inputFiles 'dirToFiles/sample1_chr_1_data.txt, dirToFiles/sample1_chr_X_data.txt, dirToFiles/sample1_chr_M_data.txt' --outputFiles result/sample1_merged_chr1XM.txt` . sorry for bothering you!